# How to use dc.js with next.js (asterisk/wildcard import issue)?

Tags: debugging, next.js, google-chrome-devtools, dc.js

Within a next.js (12.3.1) application I have a chart component where I import and use dc.js (7.6.1):

```
import * as dc from 'dc'
```

The chart is correctly shown and using an asterisk/wildcard in the import statement seems to be the only way to do so.

However, importing dc that way seems to **"destroy" the debugging feature** of Google Chrome Dev tools. The web application does not stop at breakpoints any more. And unfortunately, I do not get a warning from next.js, like "* imports are not supported" or "Debug mode stopped due to an import issue with 'dc'".  If I remove the dc import, the debugging works again as expected.

=> How to use dc.js with next.js without getting debugging issues in Google Chrome Dev Tools?

Maybe nextjs does not support asterisk/wildcard imports? It took me a while to find out that the debugging issue is due to the dc import... First thought it would be an issue with Chrome Dev Tools, a source mapping issue or an issue with a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the import from my chart component to the _app.js file of next.js. Then I pass dc down to the components as a property. That strategy somehow solves the debugging issue, don't know why exactly.

```
import React from 'react';
import * as dc from 'dc';
import './stylesheet.css'
import 'dc/dist/style/dc.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  //dc causes debugging issues when imported in chart components,
  //=> As A workaround, we import dc here and
  //pass it on to the chart components. 
  let params = {...pageProps};
  params['dc'] = dc;
  return <Component {...params} />
}

export default MyApp
```

=> Next.js seems to support `*` imports, but not on all levels of the application ?!